# Xamarin launcher icons for Google Play

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play, publish

It's my first time trying to publish my app on Google Play. I am using Xamarin 4.2 and C#.
My questions:

1. Can I use Microsoft Paint to create launcher icons?
2. My plan is to create 36x36px (ldpi), 48x48 (mdpi), 72x72 (hdpi) and 96x96 (xhdpi) launcher icons: Is this Ok so far?
   The documentation says .PNG; I guess ldpi and mdpi are just naming conventions?
   However my search found different numbers of icons and different sizes.
3. My plan is to place each of these icons under a separate folder as follows:
   Resources\drawable\drawable_ldpi\ic_launcher
   Resources\drawable\drawable_mdpi\ic_launcher
   etc. Is this arrangement correct?
4. What about the high resolution application icon: Is it placed in the resources folder? or uploaded separately into Google play console?

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at googles iconography guide: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

As you can see each density has a name, you should create a drawable_(density) folder inside the resources directory for each one you plan to support and use the correct icon size.

As an example you should have Resources/drawable_mdpi (density ñame is always in lower case)

And for the hi res icon i supose you refer to the image for google play, it is uploaded when you fill your apps description.

About using Paint to create those icons, well, using paint for anything more complex than drawing a line is a bad idea...

If you don't have any program like Photoshop you always can use Gimp, its free and very powerful:http://www.gimp.org

Comment: thanks Gusman, but can I use Microsoft Paint to draw icons? I hear that there is transparency issue. I am trying to download launcher icons templates from Android assets website and edit them in Paint but I get message: you are going to lose transparency when I save the image

Comment: Are you saving it as png?